# I have some inqure about friend list when using graph API

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api

when using graph API in terms of friends

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAC5qwrWuygObxXEkI71qQQMWplrplgIiehNQZC9CzlepI2sQoZCPIeKMpbdP7IwiVdwKY49BmJYH9E3Y8jQzD89sCoeWXRVSoUPlnW
```

if enter this URL I can see my friend list but i want to see my friend's friend list so i enter URL like this (substitute me to friend's id)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/(FRIEND'SID)/friends?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAC5qwrWuygObxXEkI71qQQMWplrplgIiehNQZC9CzlepI2sQoZCPIeKMpbdP7IwiVdwKY49BmJYH9E3Y8jQzD89sCoeWXRVSoUPlnW
```

when entering URL like this i occur some kind of authorization problem is there any other solution about this??? or another way to import my friend's friend list??

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#604) Can't lookup all friends of .... Can only lookup for the logged in user or the logged in user's friends that are users of your app.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 604
   }
}
```

It is self-explanatory. To see a friend's friend list, he must be a user of your app. The other way is to generate his `access_token`. There are no other ways you can access a friend's friend-list.

Comment: Yes. As far as I know, these are the only ways to do it. If you find the answer helpful, mark it as the "accepted answer"

Comment: sorry for asking silly question i'm new user using facebook API there are another easy way to get other person's access_token??  not just asking them??

Comment: Nope. To get a user access token, you have to have the user login to your app.

Comment: but some kinds of apps, show other friend's friend list without having access token even if they are not user of their application in this case how can they access other people's friends list??

Comment: That app must have the friend also as a user of the app. Only then can it access friend list.